# Testing BadRequest result based on Invalid Model

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit.net

I am using C#, Net Core 2.2, and XUnit testing framework.

Passing an invalid model to my Net Core WebApi it returns a bad request.
So tested in Postman and is working fine, but when I try to test it, I pass an Invalid model and there ModelState is always valid, how can I resolve this?

```
[Route("apia/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMovieRepository _movieRepository;

    public MoviesController(IMovieRepository movieRepository)
    {
        _movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }

    // GET apia/movies
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Search([FromBody] MovieFilters filters)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Ok(_movieRepository.Search(filters));
    }
}
```

And this is the model with some required attributes:

```
public class MovieFilters
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int? YearOfRelease { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

And the Test that is failing cause the ModelState is always true:

```
public class MoviesControllerTest: IClassFixture<MovieSeedDataFixture>
{
    private readonly MovieFilters _filters;
    private readonly MoviesController _controller;

    public MoviesControllerTest(MovieSeedDataFixture fixture)
    {
        var repository = new MovieRepository(fixture.MovieContext);
        _controller = new MoviesController(repository);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Search_EmptyParametersPassed_ReturnsError400()
    {
        // Act
        var result = _controller.Search(new MovieFilters());

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I made some changes and is working better now, by adding manually a ModelState error in the controller, not sure if there is better way, but is working.

So adding this line to the code

```
 _controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Required");
```

And this is the complete code again:

```
[Fact]
    public void Search_EmptyParametersPassed_ReturnsError400()
    {
        // Act
        _controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "Required");
        var result = _controller.Search(new MovieFilters());

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
    }
```

Comment: `ModelState` updated in the middleware before `controller.Search` method is executed. So "mimic" middleware by adding errors to `ModelState` would be correct approach.

Comment: Another approach is integration tests where you will test whole "pipeline", check [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2](Integration tests in ASP.NET Core)